# How to change the HTTP method by using query parameter in Java?

Tags: java, api, rest, jax-rs

My application UI client would always do GET requests. I am building a RESTful service. Is there any way I can add middleware / filter that will allow me to change the http method by reading query parameter (i.e. _method) passed. Purpose is my server REST API code don't get cluttered as it functions in standard way. I would be using JAX-RS to build RESTful API.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to be "automatically" handled by the middleware, I think you need to explain a bit more what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

you could probably implement your own Servlet [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) to do this.  in your Filter, you could wrap the existing request using [HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) and alter the method/query params as appropriate.

Comment: HttpServletRequestWrapper doesn't allow to change http method. So looks like it's not the way.

Comment: @Anil - why not?  can't you just change the result of `getMethod()`?

Comment: I was using JAX-RS provided by Apache CXF. I wanted ui client's GET request to hit method defined by POST annotation. I don't want to change just the result. Looks like HttpServletRequestWrapper doesn't allow change the http method of request object. Thanks.

Comment: @Anil - you keep saying that and i don't undestand why.  you can change the return value from getMethod() in your wrapper.